# Change text colour upon click jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following css and jquery code to attempt to change the text colour upon click of the text in the ul. If the current text colour is #d49a9a, I want to change it back to #c2c0c0 and vice versa.

```
.navContainer ul{
    left: 10px;
    top:  20px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #c2c0c0;
    font-family: 'Terminal Dosis';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 20pt;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.navContainer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c2c0c0;
}
.navContainer {
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Edit --- Here is my html

```
<head>
...some code
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#navContainer li").click( function() { 
              $("#navContainer li").css("color", "#d49a9a");
              $(this).css("color", "#c2c0c0");
            });
            </script>
</head>
<div class="navContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="navText">Work</li>
                <li class="navText"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="navText">About</li>
                <li class="navText">Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what part isn't working?

Comment: Are you firing jQuery when document is ready? Can you please provide the full code?

Comment: uh... that should be a script tag and not a style tag. can we see the html of navContainer?

Comment: Thats probably one of the reasons why it wasn't working... The question has been updated with that code.

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see what's happening.  Originally you had the wrong tag but at present you need to use `$(".navContainer li")` instead of `$("#navContainer li")` because navContainer is a class and not an id.  I've thrown a demo together which should get you going.

http://jsfiddle.net/nHJvz/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I am putting the jquery in the correct place, could you check in the question?

Comment: @XcodeDev yeah I see what you're talking about. It needs to be in a script tag and not a style tag. [Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/nHJvz/).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#navContainer li").click( function() { 
              $("#navContainer li").css("color", "#d49a9a");
              $(this).css("color", "#c2c0c0");
            });
 </script>
```

with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".navContainer li").click( function() { 
                  $(".navContainer li").css("color", "#d49a9a");
                  $(this).css("color", "#c2c0c0");
                });
    });

    </script>
```

Also make sure you are loading jQuery correctly like putting
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
in `<head>`
You may see a demo http://jsfiddle.net/CedZs/